# Android Build failed with exoplayer

Tags: java, android, gradle, exoplayer

i am including exoplayer with my application to play video. When i am running the app with emulator or phone, its working fine. But when i try to build apk, it giving the following error`Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/exoplayer2/text/CaptionStyleCompat$EdgeType.class`.

And this is my app gralde file

```
 compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile project(':tedpicker')
compile project(':multiSelectSearchLib')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
//Twitter Login
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.13.3@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}

//Splash Screen animation library
compile project(':contactPickerLib')
//Applozic chat sdk
compile project(':chatcommons')
compile project(':chatkit')
compile project(':chatkitui')
compile project(':chataudiovideo')
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}

compile project(':toro-extended')

compile 'com.wowza.gocoder.sdk.android:com.wowza.gocoder.sdk:1.0@aar'
compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.0'
compile 'com.github.glomadrian:Grav:1.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.nex3z:toggle-button-group:1.0.0'
compile 'com.appyvet:materialrangebar:1.3'
compile 'com.hbb20:ccp:1.7.6'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
```

How to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Issue fixed. Thanks

Comment: Please confirm. how did you fixed it.